# Data in the html mark up or the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in angular i will be writing 2 directives restricted to elements , take a look at the following html

```
    <sidebar collapsemode="ic">
        <item icon="xxx" notify="true">Dashboard</item>
        <item icon="yyy" notify="false">
            Settings
            <item>Proxies</item>
            <item>Users</item>
        </item>
    </sidebar>
```

i will write 2 directives restricted to elements which are sidebar and item, i am learning angular and i am not sure about one thing, writing the above html in a JSON format and adding it to a controller as the following makes it really easy for me to write the directives

```
    $scope.items = [{
    content: 'Dashboard',
    icon: 'xxx',
    notify: true
    },{
    content: 'Settings',
    icon: 'xxx',
    notify: true,
    children: [{
        content: 'Proxies'
    }, {
        content: 'Users'
    }]
  }];
```

but is it possible to manage it using the html markup without having to involve the controller, i know that it complicates things considering that i will have multiple levels of nested elements,  which way would you go with, having the data in the html markup or in JSON format in the controller and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any benefits of the HTML way. The JSON option looks much more flexible. You can manipulate the data more easily from your controllers with less typing. (Probably you can achieve the same with the HTML based solution as well, but it would be more complex, long and less clean.)